# Libgdx scene2d inputprocessor not working?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

So basically all I am trying to achieve here is very simple. Load up the game with the menu screen. Click the play button, moves to a "play screen", character dies, "home button" clicked goes back to the menu screen. However, when I try to click on the "play button" after my character dies, it does not seem to register the clicks at all. Bear in mind that on the first attempt (when the app is first opened) my buttons in the main menu class are clickable. However after i try to transition back into the same main menu class using the method updateGOSButtons() as shown below, the buttons become unclickable.

**MENU SCREEN CLASS**

```
public void show() {
        //init table and stuff
        buttonPlay.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                buttonClicked.play();
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
                dispose();
            }
        });

        buttonRate.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                buttonClicked.play();
                System.out.println("Nothing happens Yet");
            }
        });
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

**PLAY SCREEN CLASS**

```
public void updateGOSButtons() {
        if (gos.isGoButtonClicked()) {
            gameOver.stop();
            backgroundMusic.play();

            gameState = GameState.START;

            dispose();
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        }

        if (gos.isHomeButtonClicked()) {
            gameOver.stop();
            backgroundMusic.play();

            gameState = GameState.START;

            dispose();
            game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
        }

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gos.getStage());
    }
```

Comment: Are you creating a new Stage? Most of the time when my stage, buttons or whatever actor is not working it's because I create a new Object in it after I have assigned it or added Listener or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are calling the **updateGOSButtons** method in the render of GameScreen. I think that the problem can be that after setting screen to **MainScreen**

```
    if (gos.isHomeButtonClicked())
    {
        ...
```

the

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gos.getStage());
```

is called one more time and "overrides" the

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

from **MainMenu** screen which is called only once (in show method so at the start of the screen).

The solution is to move te setting of inputProcessor in a gameScreen to the **show()** method (so it will be called only once).

If you for some reason need more than one stage to be inputProcessor just use [InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) - you can read how to use it here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling

Comment: I just want to thank you for your time, this was an absolutely flawless answer. I tried adding a boolean variable to my updateGOS method to determine if it was already clicked once and if so stop updating the inputprocessor, however upon debugging I found that the method is called once more after the screen has been changed to the **MainScreen**, thus once again setting my boolean variable to false. Im not sure if Im doing it the right way currently but I solved it by just adding my inputprocessor to the render method of my **MainScreen**. Im wondering if thats the "inefficient" way of doingit